# Keep the encoding to UTF-8 in QGIS 3.22 when using tools in the Qgis toolbox?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

Is there any equivalent to this setting/data source/option in QGIS 3.22. I would like to have the default encoding of UTF-8 (right now it change the files into windows1250 when running tools in the Qgis toolbox) In 2017 this option existed, see figure, but this could not be found any more.

[image]

Comment: It might be best to use GeoPackage as an output format if possible. The shape encoding can be set with `-lco ENCODING=UTF-8` https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4359 but I do not know it it is possible to make the QGIS tools to use it.